# In my Visual Studio Setup Project how do I check if a dependent program is running?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

I'm writing an add-in for an existing program that will already be installed on the user's computer.  How can I configure my Visual Studio setup project so that it checks to see if the existing program is already running and then prompts the user to close it if it is already running?  That way it will prevent them from copying over the old version of the program that is already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer already does this for you. If it determines that that a process should be closed it pops out [MsiRMFilesInUse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  dialog.